# grpc-dotnet backwards compatibility

Tags: java, .net-core, grpc

previously I've used grpc C-core for .net 2.x and it was working fine, with groc running on .net core 2.2 on server side and C#, Java grpc clients, using pem files for TLS.

Now I've noticed that the new grpc-dptnet no longer supports pem files. Does that mean everything breaks? no more backwards compatibility? I was looking forward to use the new worker service in .net core 3 to rewrite my grpc windows service, without the front end knowing it, so front end continues to use pem files for TLS. But it seems to be impossible now.

So can someone please advice me..

1. How many types of pfx files are there? client pfx, server pfx? or just one client pfx?
2. How does Java grpc client make use of the pfx file to connect to grpc server, esp when server is done in grpc-dotnet and not the C core grpc.
3. is there a difference between the pfx cert used by IIS and the one used by grpc server? will it cause a conflict if client side pfx is used on IIS with developer SSL cert.. for the case when asp.net web appp is also running grpc service.. esp when on the same port.. then what would happen?
4. How do I detect disconnect for grpc? previously with grpc-C-core, I would call Connect first, then wait for connection change status.. now with httpClient, I don't think this is possible.. or am I wrong?

I'm finding the new grpc-dotnet far more confusing and difficult to understand than the original grpc C core for .net. At least that was clear how to config ports, certs (generating pem files using openssl was very easy and all that matters was the CN field). Now with the pfx file format, I'm really confused.. so please bear with me if I sound stupid..